# ajv validate fails with correct schema "data should NOT have additional properties"

Tags: node.js, validation, jsonschema, ajv

I'm using [ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/tree/fde7030a19833273b08e8de879cb2bf149adaf2f) to validate some JSON data before it gets written to a database. My request data essentially looks like this (as an example):

doc:

```
"name": "John",
"id": "123-456-789"
```

This gets passed to the ajv validator:

```
const validator: ajv.Ajv = this.getValidator();
validator.validate("Testschema.out", doc)
```

This is what Testschema.out looks like

```
{
    "id": "Testschema.out",
    "type": "object",
    "allOf": [{
            "$ref": "anotherId#/definitions/someDefinition"
        },
        {
            "$ref": "Testschema"
        }
    ]
}
```

Testschema holds this:

```
{
    "id": "Testschema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": [
        "name"
    ]
}
```

While someDefinition holds this:

```
{
    "id": "anotherId",
    "type": "object",
    "definitions": {
        "someDefinition": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the validation fails, and the error that I get is `"data should NOT have additional properties"` Specifically, anything in the "anotherId" schema for some reason fails validation. If I where to add the "id" property to Testschema, then validation would pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the problem is with the `allOf` keyword and `"additionalProperties": false` on "Testschema." See: https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#allof

It seems that the new `$merge` keyword is the answer for this: https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv-merge-patch